# How do I disable multiple options in multiple select tags with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom, html-select

I have a page with multiple dropdowns and I want to disable multiple options in all of those dropdowns.

The options I aim to disable share certain characteristics, namely that they're identified with two classes each. Many of the options in all the lists share the same classes and I want to add several buttons that enable or disable options based on those classes.

My issue is, that the standard ways I have seen here target options

1. by select element
2. by number.

But mine are dynamically generated and the options that I'm trying to disable are not always next to each other.

Here's a snippet of one of the dropdowns:

```
<select name="m1">
    <option value="Abyss Guard, Cereberus" class="Covert Beast">Abyss Guard, Cereberus</option>
    <option value="Abyss Guard, Cereberus+" class="Covert Beast">Abyss Guard, Cereberus+</option>
    <option value="Achlis+" class="Covert Beast">Achlis+</option>
    <option value="Adept Devil+" class="Impulse Demon">Adept Devil+</option>
    <option value="Agares+" class="Covert Demon">Agares+</option>
    <option value="Airship of Death+" class="Psycho Creation">Airship of Death+</option>
    <option value="Ancient Huge Statue+" class="Psycho Creation">Ancient Huge Statue+</option>
    <option value="Anna Thorn Maiden" class="Impulse Demon">Anna Thorn Maiden</option>
    <option value="Anna Thorn Maiden+" class="Impulse Demon">Anna Thorn Maiden+</option>
    <option value="Anomalocaris+" class="Impulse Beast">Anomalocaris+</option>
    <option value="Apopisu of Chaos+" class="Psycho Beast">Apopisu of Chaos+</option>
    <option value="Arachno Chi" class="Psycho Crawler">Arachno Chi</option>
    <option value="Arachno Chi+" class="Psycho Crawler">Arachno Chi+</option>
    <option value="Arbitration Demon+" class="Psycho Demon">Arbitration Demon+</option>
    <option value="Armored Black Tiger+" class="Impulse Beast">Armored Black Tiger+</option>
    <option value="Armored Bucephalus+" class="Covert Beast">Armored Bucephalus+</option>
</select>
```

This is by no means an exhaustive list, there's a couple of hundred options for each dropdown, though all the dropdowns contain the same list. As you can see, the list is sorted alphabetically, not by class.

I am looking to disable and enable options with a button based on one of the two classes, and a disabled status should override an enabled status. The standard `document.getElementById('m1').options[number].disabled` doesn't really help me here as the list is dynamically generated and I do not know where a specific option will end up.

Part of the site's aim is to minimize the amount of reloading needed and at the same time minimize the amount of javascript being executed, to speed up responsiveness. Is there a way I can select all options in all of the dropdowns that are of any specific class?

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('option.class_1, option.class_2')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it. If you have that many options and they don't change, consider caching the result of document.querySelectorAll so that you don't have to find all the options again each time you want to disable/enable them.

http://jsfiddle.net/uj86d/

HTML

```
<select>
    <option value="test1" class="red">Test 1</option>
    <option value="test2">Test 2</option>
    <option value="test3" class="red">Test 3</option>
    <option value="test4">Test 4</option>
</select>

<select>
    <option value="test1">Test 1</option>
    <option value="test2" class="red">Test 2</option>
    <option value="test3">Test 3</option>
    <option value="test4" class="red">Test 4</option>
</select>

<button>Disable reds!</button>
```

JS

```
//disable all options with a red class
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function () {
    var redOptions = document.querySelectorAll('option.red'),
        i = 0,
        len = redOptions.length;

    for (; i < len; i++) {
        redOptions[i].disabled = true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, this does indeed help. What about if I had wanted to enable all options of class "Covert" without enabling any options disabled by a button that disables options of class "Beast"? So if an option has class="Covert Beast" it is not enabled, but if it has any other second class, such as class="Covert Crawler" it is enabled.

Comment: You could do do `document.querySelectorAll('option.Covert:not(.Beast)')` to query all option elements that have a class `Covert` and don't have a class `Beast`. Check this link for supported CSS selectors -> http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/

Comment: not sure that will work as my design uses a total of 14 buttons, separated into two sets. there are 12 total classes. each option has for the first class 1 of 4, and for the second class 1 of 8. the one set of buttons are supposed to enable & disable based on the first class an option has, the second set enable & disable based on the second class. i am trying to create a combination sort, where if i use the button to enable class Covert(and disable the other 3 first classes) and then press the button to enable class Beast, it would enable only options that have both class Covert & class Beast.

Comment: afterwards, if i enable class Impulse instead of Covert, i want to not enable any members that are class Impulse but not class Beast. here's a link to the final website, if that helps you understand the effect i am trying to achieve: http://armitaage2.heliohost.org/ds-tools/monster/partycalc.html the buttons that i am trying to program are hidden, accessible by clicking the "Advanced" button.

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/uj86d/7/ It's not perfect right now however, because if the current selected option gets filtered out, I guess the `selectedIndex` should be set to -1, or to the first enabled option? But you should be able to implement it ;)

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly, and allows me to add any number of buttons easily. Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: Resurrecting an old topic perhaps, but I have discovered a certain issue with the code that I have accepted, which is very prevalent on chrome(not sure if it's specifically chrome only, or other webkit browsers too as I have no way to test). Using multiple classes to hide() options seems to also affect the height of the dropdown menu that appears when the select is clicked, making it smaller each time, until it becomes 0 height. Do you have any idea what may be causing this, and how I can correct this issue? This issue doesn't occur in firefox or ie, I am not sure about opera(no way to test).

Comment: Could you create a fiddle to demonstrate the issue please? I will have a look.

Comment: here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uj86d/14/ the issue occurs on chrome 27.0 for windows, not sure about other operating systems and/or other webkit browser. try selecting one button from each row and see what happens. also, the issue does not occur on chrome for android, as that simply doesn't support show()/hide() and ignores it.